# Sobreescritura de $_POST en PHP

Tags: formularios, php8

Estoy mirando de hacer un formulario en PHP 8.1.2 (aún estoy aprendiendo, son solo pruebas) y me ocurre que al utilizar un solo input, funciona bien:

```
$nombre = $_POST["nombre"] ?? null;

echo "Hola, ".$nombre;
```

El problema viene cuando intento utilizar varios inputs. Se reasignan valores y queda solo el último.

```
$nombre = $_POST["nombre"] ?? null;
$apellidos = $_POST["apellidos"] ?? null;

echo "Hola, ".$nombre;
echo $apellidos;
```

Aquí, al hacer post desde el formulario, solo queda imprimido, por ejemplo Hola, García Fuentes. Se come el nombre.

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrarnos el formulario en HTML que estas usando para ello?  Haz clic en [edit] para actualizar la pregunta con ese dato. Tiene pinta de que el error puede estar alli.

Comment: Tienes toda la razón. Tendré que tomar un descanso. El fallo más tonto del mundo, tenía mal un nombre en el atributo name de un input :) ¡Gracias de nuevo!

Comment: De nada, perfecto :-)   A descansar pues , saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estamos ante un típico caso de lo que yo llamo *programación optimista*, es decir, programar código ignorando los posibles errores.

Si en este contexto **`$nombre` y `$apellidos` son requeridos** tú no puedes proceder a un `echo`  ni a ninguna operación con esos datos sin antes verificarlos... Aquí es algo simple, y no hay gran problema, pero esto **podría convertirse en un grave problema en contextos más delicados** como inserción / actualización de bases de datos u otros.

Veamos un ejemplo donde controlas posibles errores, informando al usuario de lo que ha ocurrido:

```
$nombre = $_POST["nombre"] ?? null;
$apellidos = $_POST["apellidos"] ?? null;

if ($nombre && $apellidos) {
    /*
       En un contexto más delicado
       este bloque te asegura de que datos requeridos
       no sean insertados / actualizados como nulos o vacíos
     */
    $outPut="Hola, $nombre $apellidos";
} else {
    $outPut="Alguno de los datos requeridos no fue llenado en el formulario";
}
echo $outPut;
```

Imaginemos OTRO contexto, en el cual `$nombre` es requerido y `$apellidos` debe tener por defecto una cadena vacía:

```
$nombre = $_POST["nombre"] ?? null;
$apellidos = $_POST["apellidos"] ?? "";

if ($nombre) {
    /*
       En un contexto más delicado
       este bloque te asegura de que datos requeridos
       no sean insertados / actualizados como nulos o vacíos
     */
    $outPut="Hola, $nombre $apellidos";
} else {
    $outPut="Debes indicar un nombre válido";
}
echo $outPut;
```

Comment: Gracias por esta respuesta tan útil. Me lo guardo, me viene perfecto ahora que estoy empezando con PHP.